# why cant i use textAlignment in android studio using jetcompose

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

it shows unresolved refrence to my textAlignment please help im burned im attaching a screenshot

[image]

Comment: because you missed comma in end of text line

Comment: unnecessary question if you would have readed IDE warnings and errors before asking

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you missed a `,` at the end of line 25.

```
 Text(
    text = state.number1 + (state.operation?:"")+state.number2 ,
    textAlign = TextAlign.End 
 )
```